# BASH: Keeping formatting but substituting variables

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I would like to use a here document to store a configuration file for gnuplot within my bash script but I need to be able to substitute the bash variables whilst keeping the carriage returns.

Below if an extract of what I am using:

```
read -r -d '' GNUPLOT_CONF << 'EOF'
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Verdana, 10'
set title "This is a test"
set xrange [$SMALLEST:$LARGEST]
EOF
```

If I

```
echo $GNUPLOT_CONF
```

then the variables get correctly substituted but all the carriage returns gets stripped out (and therefore gnuplot fails to execute it) and if I

```
echo "$GNUPLOT_CONF"
```

then the formatting is right but the variables are not substituted (and gnuplot fails)

The gnuplot commands an be set to variable but then all the special characters like the quotes need to be escaped.   Is there a happy medium using here docs which makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply drop the quotes from `'EOF'`

```
read -r -d '' GNUPLOT_CONF << EOF
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Verdana, 10'
set title "This is a test"
set xrange [$SMALLEST:$LARGEST]
EOF
```

Your original code and the changed one differed only in substitution when I tried:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Verdana, 10' set title "This is a test" set xrange [$SMALLEST:$LARGEST]
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Verdana, 10' set title "This is a test" set xrange [1:9]
```

Fun fact: vim changes the syntax highlighting immediately when you drop the quotes and highlights the variable substitutions in the here doc.

Comment: +1. Documented at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: I think you should show the different outputs of `echo "$GNUPLOT_CONF"`, because for `gnuplot` it is essential that the newlines are kept (which is not the case in the output you show).

Comment: Cheers, that solved it. 

I needed to add comments to the start and end as when the multiple of these are echoed together, the last and first lines joined.