# How to use database (or bash array) values for line properties in gnuplot?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a database file that looks like:

```
aaa bb ccc 2 3.34534 kkk 3 4.5099 34%
rr wie fff 4 4.59050 asd 6 5.0983 1.345%
```

I need to plot a range starting at the 'y' value of the 5th column (i.e. 3.34534) up to the value on the 8th column. Or lets say, a y=3.34534 line with line width of 4.5099-3.34534 for the first line. Or, some sort of filled curve between y=3.34534 and y=4.5099 for the first line. This has to be done for all lines a filled curve between the value on the 5th column and the 8th column. The question is, how to access those values and input them into gnuplot. A shell script maybe? (So far I have managed to save the values to an array x() and y(): for value in column5 first line accessed by ${x[0]} and the one in the 8th column to ${y[0]}, the question now would be how to input values from the array into the gnuplot syntax via EOF>>). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have everything together in the bash script, you can first define a variable, which contains all gnuplot code (see e.g. [BASH: Keeping formatting but substituting variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18771443/2604213)):

```
read -r -d '' GNUPLOT_SCRIPT <<EOF
set xrange [0:1];
plot x
EOF
```

Note, that with that construct every line of the gnuplot code must be terminated with a `;`.

For the plotting I would use the `boxxyerrorbars` plotting style, which plots boxes at a point with a given width and height. In the gnuplot `using` statement, the first and second value are the `x` and `y` values of the box *center*, the third and fourth values give the *half* box width and height.

You didn't say anything about the `x`-values, so I chose the `xrange` to be from `0` to `1`.

Assuming, that you "database" is in a string, the bash script looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

database="aaa bb ccc 2 3.34534 kkk 3 4.5099 34%
rr wie fff 4 4.59050 asd 6 5.0983 1.345%"

read -r -d '' GNUPLOT_SCRIPT <<EOF
set xrange[0:1];
set style fill solid 1.0;
set style data boxxyerrorbars;
unset key;
plot '-' using (0.5):(0.5*(column(5)+column(8))):(0.5):(abs(0.5*(column(5) - column(8))))
EOF

echo "$database" | gnuplot -persist -e "$GNUPLOT_SCRIPT"
```

If you want to save the plot in a file, you don't need the `-persist` option.

Comment: Thanks, it works and plots exactly what I wanted. Using the boxxyerrorbars multiplying by 0.5 to have x and y bars half of the size for the whole size being the distance I wanted is nice too. I want to integrate this with some other plots. Using column(n) and error bars was all I needed. I am still curious in how to access a value in an array of the type: ${x[@]} by gnuplot but your answer does the job, so no need to overcomplicate things. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the approach if the data was in a file.dat instead?

Comment: Gnuplot itself cannot access any bash variables directly. So it is all about formatting the data with bash and piping this ready-made string block to gnuplot. Don't know how to do that best with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself the other part of the question, I figured out how to do it from a file.dat Assuming the database is not in a string but in file.dat, and the result is out as a .png image.

```
gnuplot << EOF
set terminal png
set output "niceplot.png"
plot "file.dat" using (0.5):(0.5*(column(5)+column(9))):(0.5):(abs(0.5*(column(5) - column(9)))) with boxxy fs solid 1 noborder lc rgb "red" title "Range"
EOF
```

Where, fs solid 1 noborder lc rgb "red" title "Range", is some styling for gnuplot.
Thanks Christoph for suggesting the error box.

Comment: You should use the `pngcairo` terminal, which gives much better output. (Note, that in some cases the `png` terminal is redirected to the `pngcairo` terminal, but in general the `png` terminal is a distinct one which uses the libgd).